# Mule ESB Java Component 3.8 Doc

Tags: mule, mule-component

I am trying to reply the basic Java Component Example from the Official Documentation:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/java-component-reference

The IDE is v.6.0.1

I realized that the Java class should extend Callable. This is mainly the big difference with previous versions of MULE. So in my case

```
package javacomponent;

import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;
import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable;

public class helloWorldComponent implements Callable{
@Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
        eventContext.getMessage().setInvocationProperty("myProperty", "Hello World!");
        return eventContext.getMessage().getPayload();
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that after running the app and making a http/get to localhost:8081 I can't se the Hello World! message rendered in the browser.

Has something changed in last version? Should I incluse a setPayload element also?

Answer (score 2):

Referring the code it sets an *Invocation Property* or *Variable*, and returns the existing *Payload* which can be `{NullPayload}` because not defined yet. Try to debug and evaluate the *Variables* tab inside *Mule Debugger*, You should find a new variable named: `myProperty`.

In order to get the basic Hello World text then do one of the following option:

1. Set the *Payload* instead of the *Invocation Property* (replace or add it to existing code): `eventContext.getMessage().setPayload("Hello World!");`
2. Returns the *Invocation Property* instead of the *Payload*: `return eventContext.getMessage().getInvocationProperty("myProperty");`

Comment: Thanks that works for me! Now I understand why payload was null I assigned the message to it and could render in the browser.-

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is that you are instantiating the Java class correctly. The UI or visual way of configuring the Java object is not clear to me. I found a very simple example of Spring configuration like so:

```
    <spring:bean id="ordersTransform" name="OrdersTransformSingleton" class="org.dlw.transport.OrdersTransformSingleton" scope="singleton" />
```

And, the Java object component:

Check this first and be sure that you are instantiating your class at runtime. Then add a breakpoint in the callable method you implemented and just see if the application program pointer is getting you in the method. If so, add your message to the payload.

```
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
    // freshen
    this.transportObj = null;
    this.transportObj = new ArrayList<OrdersValueObject>();

    MuleMessage res = eventContext.getMessage();
    List<Map> list = (LinkedList) res.getPayload();
  ...       
    res.setPayload(transportObj);
    return res;
}
```

Remember to set the payload and return the message.

Comment: In the configuration XML I defined the Java class like this: <component class="javacomponent.helloWorldComponent" doc:name="Java"/> after setting the paylod works for me.-